# process not starting in python

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have created two processes but they are not starting according to this code.
any idea what is the problem?

```
import serial
from multiprocessing import Process

ser=serial.Serial('COM8',115200)

c=" "
out=" "

def pi():
 print ("started")
 out=" "
 while 1:
 #  loop contents

def man():

 while(1):
  # loop contents

p1=Process(target=pi,args=())
p2=Process(target=man,args=())

p1.start() 
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the there is no problem while instantiating the serial port? Maybe you can try introducing a timeout? Also, where exactly does the execution differ? Does the code print 'started' or does it fail before that?

Comment: No, the print statement is not executed.When I run it there is no output.the problem is not with the serial port because it was working fine before when i was not using the multiprocessing.

Comment: @user2572946: I think what spiritusozeans is suggesting is that you add a `print("launching children")` before calling `p1.start()` and/or before creating `p1`, to make sure you're actually getting to that part of the code.

Comment: @abarnet I tested that , I am getting the print output but nothing else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll guess you're using windows...

Put your initalisation code in an `if __name__ == '__main__':` block:

```
import serial
from multiprocessing import Process

ser=serial.Serial('COM8',115200)

c=" "
out=" "

def pi():
    print ("started")
    out=" "
    while 1:
    #  loop contents

def man():

    while(1):
        # loop contents

if __name__ == '__main__':

    p1=Process(target=pi,args=())
    p2=Process(target=man,args=())

    p1.start() 
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
```

On windows, to work around the lack of `fork()` each newly started subprocess has to import the `__main__` module, so you'll run into an endless loop of spawning processes unless if you don't protect your initialistion code.

Comment: yes I m using windows and i added 'if __name__ == '__main__':' but still there is no difference in the output.

Comment: I can only guess, but you should be aware that `ser=serial.Serial('COM8',115200)` is called in every subprocess again, creating a new connection. I'm only guessing, but could it be that that's blocking somehow? try adding a print statement before and after that call. or better, move it into the `__main__` block also.

Comment: thanks for helping..but still it is not working, I even deleted the serial statement then also nothing, I am not even getting an error.this means the process 'pi' is not started , because in the original code i am referring to serial port in that function

Comment: @user2572946: But in the original, you're not referring to the serial port in multiple processes at the same time, and that could very easily block even if doing it in one process doesn't.